# Для чего значения атрибута crossorigin="use-credentials" в html-е?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, cors, атрибуты

здраствуйте...сможетье обеснить мне, для чего значениа "use-credentials". я знаю что это для того, чтобы отправить данныые cookies, ssl sertifikat и HTTP-аутентификации, но не понимаю для чего я должен мои данные отправить. я могу использовать "anonymous", но какой смысл использовать значения "use-credentials".

Comment: Например, для скачивания с других ресурсов (конкретней, отображение ошибок и т.п.), для "имитации" источника в canvas и т.п.. Вы никому ничего не должны, если нет непонимания - не стоит никуда ничего отправлять "ради забавы"

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ.